# What is a good approach for warning user on leaving a modal or side flyout panel with unsaved changes?

Tags: forms, navigation, validation, warnings

The user is editing a form element on the RHS flyout panel and the editing is not completed. In the middle of the process, the user decides to undertake the following actions:

1. Click outside the flyout panel.
2. Click in the search bar.
3. Click on one of the tabs inside the flyout
4. Clicks on the flyout close button.

[image: Right Hand Side Flyout Panel]

What is the best way to notify the user that their changes will not be saved? Here are some of my iterations:

[image: iterations of notifying users about unsaved changes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having a pop-up modal asking the user that there is unsaved information that he will lose.

It's weird to click somewhere on the platform and have a warning somewhere else. Don't make the user chase warning messages on the platform. Make messaging contextual.

Facebook has a good example of this interaction here if you try to navigate to another page without posting your comment or status.

[image]

And here is a default browser warning triggered by StackExchange:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have read a lot of posts saying that modals are distracting and annoying for the users if they come up too often, and I anticipate that in this interaction this could be the case. Could there be a 'softer' way of notifying users without popping a modal?

Comment: I totally agree. Here is the tradeoff that you need to do as a designer between:

1. User will lose information and be super annoyed
2. Annoy user with a modal to save the information and not be super annoyed

Comment: True! that's a good way of looking at it!